# Clear search bar

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear a search bar. The idea was to search through a list in a table. A search function is called onkeyup from an input then I added an icon eraser that clears the input onclick (span).

Even though the input is cleared, the search is still displayed with the list of result from the search. I would like to get back to the whole list on the click of the eraser icon.
Any suggestion?

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      found = false;
    } else if (!tr[i].id.match('^tableHeader')) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="search-box pull-left">
  <form action="">
    <input type="search" id="searchInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in anything">
    <span id="clearSearch" onclick="document.getElementById('searchInput').value = null;">
            <i class="ti-eraser"></i>
        </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the input field value via script, does not trigger any event handlers. Simply explicitly calling your `search` function after you emptied the value should probably work.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with an example of the table you have

Comment: "I would like to get back to the whole list on the click of the eraser icon." What does this mean?

Comment: By the way, instead of `onkeyup` you better use `oninput`, because what if the input was done with the mouse instead of keys (dragging text into the field, right-clicking and pasting) or without input device at all (autofill)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean adding search to the event handler of the clear?

Note I moved the inline event handlers and changed to the better "input" event since it handles paste too and changed the null to an empty string

It would have been easier to test if I had your table

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("clearSearch").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('searchInput').value = "";
    search();
  });
  document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("input", search)  
});
```

```js
const search = () => {
  var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
      if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
      found = false;
    } else if (!tr[i].id.match('^tableHeader')) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("clearSearch").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('searchInput').value = "";
    search();
  });
  document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("input", search)  
});
```

```html
<div class="search-box pull-left">
  <form action="">
    <input type="search" id="searchInput"  placeholder="Search..." title="Type in anything">
    <span id="clearSearch">
            <i class="ti-eraser"></i>
        </span>
  </form>
</div>

<table id="list"><tbody>
<tr><td>Some text</td></tr> 
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: How *exactly* did you solve this without "do you mean this?"

Comment: Pretty obvious, but ok, I made it more obvious